# Подскажите как в Fancybox 3,4,.. сделать галлерею локальных виедо в лайтбоксах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не получается использовать в lightbox 4 теги  , вот yourtube видео работает как надо.

`<a href="https://youtu.be/eRrlH0Rv-3k" data-fancybox="gallery">`

Comment: https://codepen.io/ericjacksonwood/pen/ZOdpEP

Comment: Всё отлично заработало, благодарю! Не подскажете ещё, что надо дописать что бы при клике на стрелочку прокрутки и на пустую область при закрытии лайтбокса,текущие проигрываемые видео останавливались https://c2n.me/4harGT1  ?

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/x7scogeu/